# Creating abstract javascript classes with Microsoft asp.net ajax client library

Tags: javascript, interface, asp.net-ajax, abstract-class

**note:** for those SO fellow developers MS Ajax javascript library emulates classes, interface, enums and other OO features but the language does not support it. So don't start bragging there isn't a class in javascript.

#### Interface Implementation

```
/// <reference path="MicrosoftAjax.debug.js" />

Type.registerNamespace("Validators");

Validators.IValidate = function () {
    throw Error.notImplemented("Interface IValidate must be implemented before invoke.");
};

Validators.IValidate.prototype = {
    ErrorMessage: "",
    IsValid: false,
    Validate: function () {
        throw Error.notImplemented("Class must provide a implementation for the method");
    }
};
Validators.IValidate.registerInterface("Validators.IValidate");
```

#### Explanation:

Why am i explaining interface which doesn't relate to the question? i will explain as it goes. The above code will create a Interface `IValidate` that mimics [IValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ivalidator.aspx) from the framework. The work of those `Error.notImplemented` code is as below

- Does not allow others to do this `new Validators.IValidate()` (i.e) no instance
- When a class implements the Interface, `Validate()` method will throw a error when not implemented

So now you must have understood how the emulation is performed. Similarly i created a class (actually i wanted a abstract class that's why i am here), named `BaseValidator` like this

```
Validators.BaseValidator = function () {
    throw Error.invalidOperation("Base validator is a abstract class. Inherit the class to work with it");
};

Validators.BaseValidator.prototype = {
    ValidationProperty: function (propertyName) {
    },
    BackColor: function (hexCode) {
    },
    ControlToValidate: function (id) {
    },
    CssClass: function (css) {
    },
    Display: function (mode) {
    },
    Focus: function () {
    }
};

Validators.BaseValidator.registerClass("Validators.BaseValidator", null, Validators.IValidate);
```

at the last line you can notice that it implements Interface (but does not provide Implementation, because it will be provided by child classes of `BaseValidator` class). When ever a class implements Interface, inherits another class the constructor function should call `Validators.BaseValidator.initializeBase(this)` which would initialize base class. Now coming to the problem read carefully please

#### Problem

```
Validators.RequiredFieldValidator = function () {
    Validators.RequiredFieldValidator.initializeBase(this, []);
};
Validators.RequiredFieldValidator.prototype = {};
Validators.RequiredFieldValidator.registerClass("Validators.RequiredFieldValidator", Validators.BaseValidator);
```

- RequiredFieldValidator inherits BaseValidator as base class
- In the constructor calls the `initializeBase(this)` to initialize base class BUT
  **Constructor in the BaseClass throws a error**.

#### Question

How am i supposed to emulate a abstract class with Microsoft Asp.net Ajax

Comment: @Raynos god stop down voting did you read the note at the top of question. Microsoft Ajax is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397536.aspx and Microsoft supports it. We have no other means of implementing ajax in asp.net.

Comment: "no other means of implementing ajax in asp.net". Sorry what? WHAT? Ever heard of `XMLHTTPRequest` ? Stop using the useless junk microsoft gives you.

Comment: @Deeptechtons ??  People do Ajax *all the time* in ASP.NET with all kinds of frameworks. You can use any JavaScript technique you like; the server framework doesn't care.

Comment: @Pointy and Raynos way off topic. If you can be constructive please provide a aanswer and do answer if you ONLY knew what the client library has to offer thanks

Comment: @Deeptechtons not way of topic. You think you have a problem and were telling you that your actual problem is using "MS ajax library". Use a decent ajax utility and all your problems dissappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the constructor calls the initializeBase(this) to initialize base class BUT Constructor in the BaseClass throws a error

`Validators.RequiredFieldValidator = function () { };`

What's wrong with simply not calling the super constructor. If the constructor your inheriting from is meant to be abstract (a useless thing to do) then simply don't ever call it.